# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of null using Openerp 7.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, exception, openerp-7

I am using [Openerp](https://www.openerp.com) (Version 7.0-20140429-231256). It was working well for a while one bad day I got a below error. And I don't find any reference to solve the exception.

```
OpenERP Client Error
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of null
http://localhost:8069/web/webclient/js?db=openerp:3268
```

In process of debug I wanted to get to the root of problem. Some how I observed that there is openerp.init jquery triggers all the modules where its missing most of the modules which are installed..
i.e.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                var s = new openerp.init(["web", "web_kanban", "base", "base_setup", "process", "base_import", "web_view_editor", "web_calendar", "web_diagram", "board", "web_gantt", "web_graph", "web_tests"]);
                var wc = new s.web.WebClient();wc.appendTo($(document.body));
            });
        </script>
```

Though I have installed many module like Point of Sale, Ware house management, Mailing etc. Its not included in init function.

I have installed several module available in openerp not community modules. Am not able to move forward with this error. Please help me how I can able to fix this problem.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: use appendTo('body') instead.....\

Comment: Hello thanks for reply, but Its showing same error. I see problem only exist with one particular database. Other Db don't throw error. I think this problem has nothing to do with code. Maybe module should have caused the problem...

Comment: After debugging the code have found that module information are stored in one particular table called ***ir_module_module***, in this table it store the state of module..
i.e. 
 *1. installed 
 2. uninstalled 
 3. to remove*

But many of modules are in ***to remove*** state. So I used update statement for postgressql (which is similar to mysql) to update all ***to remove*** to ***installed***

here is update statement which is used to update table.

     update ir_module_module set state ='installed' where state='to remove';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem myself.

Though want to share details with you. So that anyone come across same, then this reference might be helpful.

After debugging the code have found that module information are stored in one particular table called ***ir_module_module***, in this table it store the state of module..
i.e.

*1. installed 
 2. uninstalled 
 3. to remove*

So when we start openerp server then it fetch for modules for js to load which are installed state.

But many of modules are in ***to remove*** state. So I used update statement for postgressql (which is similar to mysql) to update all ***to remove*** to ***installed***

here is update statement which is used to update table.

```
 update ir_module_module set state ='installed' where state='to remove';
```

**Though I have no idea how in first play module went into ***to remove*** state.

Comment: Men I have to say HUGE THANKS! for this answer! you save my day!